# Get the label from ACF checkbox

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I feel like this should be easy but for some reason I can't get this to work?

I have several similar but distinct colors in list of products. I need to be able to grap the label to show to the end user (so they see orange instead of m_orange) but I also need the value to be distinct so I can apply the appropriate class to the element.

orange : orange
m_orange : orange
purple : purple
m_purple : purple
w_purple : purple

My code:

```
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
$color = get_field('color');
?>

<?php foreach($color as $color_list){echo "<li >$color_list <span class=\"color_text_slash\"> / </span> </li>";}?>  

 <?php foreach($color as $color_class){echo "<li class=\"$color_class\"></li>" ;}?>
```

I tried to follow instructions at http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/checkbox/  but it hasn't worked and I can't seem to figure this out?

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

```
$field = get_field_object('color'); 
$colors = get_field('color'); // array of selected color values 
foreach($colors as $color){
    echo "selected color: ". $color. " with label: " . $field['choices'][ $color ];
}
```

where the labels are fetched by `get_field_object` according to the link you provided.

You could also use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to check what is stored in the variables `$field` and `$colors`.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it with `print_r()` checks.

**Try this:**

```
$field = get_field_object('color'); 
$colors = get_field('color');

foreach($colors as $key => $val) {
    $label = $colors[$key];
    echo 'This is your label: '. $field['choices'][$label]; 
}
```

*'choices' is where your labels are stored*