# ACF checkbox array is returning numbers, not labels

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, array, php

I am using Advanced Custom Fields and the add-on Repeater to create a field in the admin through which a user can select multiple icons. Each icon has an associated label, and I'm trying to return the results of the checked icons in a `foreach` loop. Here's my code:

```
<?php
// icons
foreach (get_sub_field('nav_widget_platforms') as $label => $value) {
    echo '<div class="mps-nav-context"><i class="icon-'.$value.'" title="'.$label.'"></i><span>'.$label.'</span></div>';
}
?>
```

So for example, if the checkbox `cloud : eCommerce` is selected, the `$value` should be `cloud`, and the `$label` should be `eCommerce`.

The problem is that `$label` is returning numbers, not labels, so that the page is displaying `0`, `1`, etc. depending on which order it is in the array.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, or how to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACF is actually doing what it should - storing a numerical array of selected values. If you want the label you can levy `get_field_object`, which returns information about the custom field (rather than the value of it for the given post).

```
$field_obj = get_field_object( 'nav_widget_platforms' ); 
$platforms = get_field( 'nav_widget_platforms' ); 
foreach ( $platforms as $platform ){
    echo $field_obj['choices'][ $platform ] . ": $platform<br />";
}
```

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/90406/1685

Comment: How would I apply this solution to my code above? I'm sorry, I don't understand the syntax of arrays well enough to interpret how to use this answer.

Comment: I figured it out! The problem was that this is a repeater field, so I had to use `get_sub_field_object` and `get_sub_field` instead, but then it worked like a charm. Thanks!